# gcc size_t and sizeof arithmetic conversion to int

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, gcc-warning

I decided to test compile a project with -Wsign-conversion enabled, to see what warnings would come up, and came across something that doesn't seem right, where gcc behaves differently than clang. Can someone please tell me which is correct?

I have a function that takes a `size_t` param:

```
void func(size_t) {}
```

some other struct

```
struct Test {};
```

and calling code

```
int i = some_initialiser();
func(sizeof(Test) + static_cast<size_t>(i));
```

So from my understanding, `sizeof` returns `size_t`, and arithmetic between two variables of type `size_t` should return a `size_t`, so there shouldn't be any conversion here other than my `static_cast`, but gcc gives me the warning

```
 warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

Clang doesn't warn here, but does warn if I remove the `static_cast` in the function call, as expected.

Comment: The more verbose error messages with gcc 9 point towards the static_cast as the source of the warning. The warning goes away if only the static_cast gets passed as a parameter. gcc seems to have a beef with the `int` getting converted to `size_t`, but only for the addition operation. Apparently an explicit cast to `size_t` is insufficient to shut it up for the `+` operator, but it keeps it silent if the result is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Something interesting to note is that if I move the `sizeof` into a local variable, it warns if it's declared as `auto`, but not if it's declared as `size_t`. Perhaps something odd in the return type of `sizeof`?

Comment: Surely the warning pertains to the conversion from `i` to `size_t`, not the addition . Perhaps clang treats the explicit cast as programmer meta-communication to suppress the warning

Comment: @M.M in asking the question, I was assuming that the warning does what the documentation says it does and only warn on implicit conversions, so was thinking for some reason gcc was doing an implicit conversion somewhere in that call. As stated in the now-accepted answer, the issue is in gcc's implementation of the warning not matching its documentation, not that it's doing an unexpected implicit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in gcc, fixed in versions 9.3.0 and above.

The warning is valid (compilers can warn about anything they like), but gcc's behavior contradicts its own documentation. There is an existing bug report for this problem (see below).

Here's a simpler test case that illustrates the issue:

```
#include <cstddef>
int main() {
    int i = 42;
    size_t s0 = sizeof (int) + (size_t)i;
    size_t s1 = sizeof (int) + static_cast<size_t>(i);
}
```

When I compile it on my system using gcc 9.1.0, I get:

```
$ g++ -Wsign-conversion -c c.cpp
c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:4:32: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    4 |     size_t s0 = sizeof (int) + (size_t)i;
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
c.cpp:5:32: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    5 |     size_t s1 = sizeof (int) + static_cast<size_t>(i);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$
```

Note that the warning occurs both for a C-style cast and for a `static_cast`.

It's true that the conversion may change the sign of the result (converting a negative `int` to `size_t` yields a positive result), but gcc's documentation for `-Wsign-conversion` says:

```
'-Wsign-conversion'
     Warn for implicit conversions that may change the sign of an
     integer value, like assigning a signed integer expression to an
     unsigned integer variable.  An explicit cast silences the warning.
     In C, this option is enabled also by '-Wconversion'.
```

In this case, an explicit cast is not silencing the warning.

This bug had already been reported:
[Bug 87519 - -Wsign-conversion -Wconversion explicit cast fails to silence warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87519)

The fix is commit `61e52125c935279af11b10d27060a96bff7477a4` in the gcc git repo, committed 2019-08-08.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed that the warning was correctly implemented and that there was some sort of unexpected implicit conversion happening, but that makes sense - for some reason, in certain contexts the explicit cast fails to silence the warning.

Answer (score -2):

The warning is correct.

If `i` has a negative value the casting will be problematic. Your function should return an unsigned value (e.g. unsigned int).

From GCC documentation - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html:

> For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type conversion operator: conversions to `void`, the same type, a base class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless `-Wsign-conversion` is explicitly enabled.

Comment: It's not supposed to warn for the explicit cast, only for implicit ones. There is no warning without performing arithmetic on the result of the cast with the result of `sizeof`.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua: Who says it's not supposed to warn for explicit casts? Compilers can warn about anything they like. (BTW, there's n no such thing as an "implicit cast"; a cast is an explicit conversion.)

Comment: @JohnIlacqua: But the behavior does seem to contradict gcc's documentation. The OP explicitly used `-Wsign-conversion` when invoking gcc, and the documentation says "An explicit cast silences the warning".

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the relevant text from the GCC documentation. Hope this now clarifies it.

Comment: It turns out this is a known bug in gcc. See my answer.

Comment: @Tomer: The docs you linked specify for `-Wsign-conversion` itself (emphasis added): "Warn for *implicit* conversions that may change the sign of an integer value, like assigning a signed integer expression to an unsigned integer variable. *An explicit cast silences the warning.*" The cast here is explicit, the addition is `size_t + size_t` and the result is passed as `size_t`, so no implicit casting is occurring.